# Using redux to take a time on a stopwatch and put it into a database

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux

I was recommended using redux to place a time into a database but I'm having issues. I have a stopwatch in my index.js that the user can start and stop. After, I have a button that allows them the ability to to put their time into a database. From my node file, I'm getting `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: null value in column "time" violates not-null constraint`. I'm wondering if I'm getting that because I have `difference = 0` at the stop of the index file and it doesn't retrieve `difference = this.state.endTime - this.state.startTime;` or if there is another issue I'm not seeing.

index.js

```
export let difference = 0;

export default class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props);
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      startTime: 0,
      endTime: 0,
    }
  }

  handleStart = () => {
    this.setState({
      startTime: Date.now()
    })
  }

  handleStop = () => {
    this.setState({
      endTime: Date.now()
    })
  }

  render() {
    difference = this.state.endTime - this.state.startTime;
    return (
      <App />
      <reducer />
    );
  }
}
```

reducer.js

```
import * as actionTypes from "./actions.js";
import difference from "../pages/index.js";

const initialState = {
    count: 0
}

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.NUMBER:
            return { state, count: difference };
        default: return state;
    }
};

export default reducer;
```

store.js

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import reducer from './reducer';

const store = createStore(reducer);






export default store;
```

actions.js

```
export const NUMBER = 'NUMBER';
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { addName } from "./util";

function App() {
  const [name, setName] = React.useState("")

  function handleUpdate(evt) {
    setName(evt.target.value);
  }

  async function handleAddName(evt) {
    await addName(name);
  }

  return <div>
    <p><input type='text' value={name} onChange={handleUpdate} /></p>
    <button className='button-style' onClick={handleAddName}>Add Name</button>
  </div>
}

export default App;
```

util.js

```
import "isomorphic-fetch"
import difference from "../pages/index.js";

export function addName(name) {
    return fetch('http://localhost:3001/addtime', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ name, time: difference }) 
    })
}
```

node server.js

```
app.post("/addtime", cors(), async (req,res) => {
    const name = req.body.name;
    const time = req.body.time;
    const timeStamp = dateFormat(time, dateFormat.masks.isoDateTime);
    
    const template = 'INSERT INTO times (name,time) VALUES ($1,$2)';
    const response = await pool.query(template, [name,time]);
    
    res.json({name: name, time: time});

});
```

Comment: The way you are implementing your redux store is all wrong.  I can leave a more detailed answer in a bit, but you are misunderstanding some really fundamental concepts here so I recommend that you read the docs for redux and the react-redux bindings.

Comment: You are storing difference as a local variable.  You want to be storing it in your redux store and accessing it by wrapping your App in a Provider component.  You would use redux selectors to retrieve the current value, either via the connect HOC or the useSelector hook. And you would dispatch actions to the redux store to update the value.  For this app redux doesn’t really provide any advantage over local component state.  You may want to use local state so that you don’t need to learn redux.

Comment: Off another question I asked on here, I learned it would be easiest to handle with a global state using redux so I've been trying to learn that. I want it to export a variable from my main class, index, and then I'm assuming through my reducer class it's saving it as a global variable. Next, I want to place that global variable in the database.

Comment: Behind the scenes Redux uses the React context API https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html to make the state globally available.  You want to use Redux when the global state that you are dealing with is a complicated object.  Your global state is just a single number so you could use Context directly.  But your App right now is just two components so even that seems unnecessary.

Comment: A `reducer` is not a component.  You cannot do `<reducer />`.

Comment: I'm working on an answer for you but this is not a case where you just need to change one line.  The whole setup is very wrong.

Comment: Okay, I understand and I appreciate any help. I'm currently reading on the context page. I'm guessing it would be best for me to remove redux entirely from my application and go with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### State Management

In React we manage changing values through state.  There is a way to access the value and a way to update the value.  When the value changes, React knows to re-render the component.

This state can be stored within a component of your app.  When you write `const [name, setName] = React.useState("")`, `name` is your "getter" and `setName` is your "setter".

The state can also be stored inside a [Context `Provider`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextprovider) component that is a parent of the current component.  Any children of this `Provider` can use the [`useContext` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) to access the stored value.

The React Redux package uses these React contexts to make the redux state globally available.  You wrap your entire `App` in a [Redux `Provider` component](https://react-redux.js.org/api/provider) to enable access.

With Redux, your "getters" are selector functions, which you call though `useSelector`, and your "setters" are actions that you pass though the `dispatch` function.  React actually supports this syntax of state management on a local component level (without Redux) though the [`useReducer` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer).

You don't need to use contexts in order to pass around state from component to component.  You can also pass values and "setters" as props from a parent component to a child.  React recommends this approach and has a section on [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

This is just a brief overview of some of the concepts at play.  The issues that you are having here are due to state management.  There are many possible ways to handle your state here.  In my opinion Redux and Contexts are both unnecessary overkill.  Of course you can use them if you want to, but you need to set them up properly which you haven't done.

### Errors

```
export let difference = 0;
```

Variables which exist at the top-level of a file, outside of a component, should be immutable constants only.  When you have a value that changes, it needs to be part of your app state.

When you have a "stateful" value like `difference` you can't just use a variable that exists outside of your components.

```
render() {
   difference = this.state.endTime - this.state.startTime;
   ...
```

This is not how you update a value.  We don't want to be just setting a constant.  We also don't want to trigger changes of a stateful value on every render as this creates infinite re-render situations.

```
handleStart & handleStop
```

The functions themselves are fine but they are never called anywhere.  Therefore `difference` will always be `0`.

```
<reducer />
```

A reducer is not a component so you cannot call it like this.  It is a pure function.  In order to introduce redux into your JSX code, you use the reducer to create a `store` variable and you pass that store to a react-redux `Provider` component.

```
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.NUMBER:
            return { state, count: difference };
        default: return state;
    }
};
```

You want to include the `difference` as a property of your `action` rather than accessing an external variable.  The standard convention is to add a `payload` property to the action.  The payload could be the difference `number` itself or an `object` with a property `difference`.  That sort of design choice is up to you.  An action might look like `{ type: actionTypes.NUMBER, payload: 0.065 }` or  `{ type: actionTypes.NUMBER, payload: { difference: 0.065 } }`.

Your `state` is an object with a property `count`.  Your reducer should return the next state, which should also be an object with a property `count`.  This will not return the right state shape: `return { state, count: difference };`.

It is typical to use the spread operator `...` to copy all other properties of the state and update just one (or a few), like this: `return { ...state, count: difference }`.  However your `state` does not have any other properties, so that is the same as `return { count: difference };`.  Since you are just storing a single number, there is no value from the previous state that is copied or preserved.  (Which is a large part of why I think that Redux is not helpful or necessary here.)

There may be some issues on the backend as well, but there are such serious issues with the front end that I think that's your main problem.

### Structuring Components

Think about what your app needs to do.  What actions does it respond to?  What information does it need to know?

Based on your description, it needs to:

- Start a timer when a button is clicked
- Stop a timer when a button is clicked
- Store the most recent timer value
- Allow a user to enter and update a name
- Store that name
- POST to the backend when a button is clicked, if there is a stored difference and name

Next you break that up into components.  Store each stateful value at the highest component in the tree which needs to access it, and pass down values and callbacks as props.  The `startTime` and `endTime` are only used by the timer itself, but the timer need to set the `difference` after stopping.  The `difference` would be stored higher up because it is also needed for the POST request.

Think about what buttons and actions are available at any given time, and what conditions are used to determine this.  For example, you shouldn't be able to stop a timer before you have started it.  So we would see if `startTime` is greater than `0`.

### Minimal Front-End Example

```
import * as React from "react";

const Timer = ({ setDifference }) => {
  const [startTime, setStartTime] = React.useState(0);

  const handleStart = () => {
    setStartTime(Date.now());
  };

  const handleStop = () => {
    const difference = Date.now() - startTime;
    setDifference(difference);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleStart}>
        Start
      </button>
      <button disabled={startTime === 0} onClick={handleStop}>
        Stop
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

const Submission = ({ time }) => {
  const [name, setName] = React.useState("");

  function handleUpdate(evt) {
    setName(evt.target.value);
  }

  async function handleAddName(evt) {
    return await fetch("http://localhost:3001/addtime", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({ name, time })
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Time: {time}</div>
      <input type="text" value={name} onChange={handleUpdate} />
      <button onClick={handleAddName} disabled={name.length === 0}>
        Add Name
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [time, setTime] = React.useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <Timer setDifference={setTime} />
      {time > 0 && <Submission time={time} />}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-65835023-b8ccv?file=/src/App.js:0-1320)

Answer (score 0):

You might not be saving any value to DOB column, you need to allow NULL value. You should change to
DOB = models.DateField(auto_now = False, null = True)
You should also make sure DOB column in your table allows null.